# htaccess not working with ~username Path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am working on a new website, which still has to be connected to a domain name via DNS. So, at the moment I am working with `http://ipaddress/~username/public_html/`

I am having a problem with making internal redirects work in my htaccess file, which sits at `http://ipaddress/~username/public_html/`

I need to map `http://ipaddress/~username/public_html/work/` to `http://ipaddress/~username/public_html/projects/index.php`

Here is what I have:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /~username/public_html/
RewriteRule ^work/?$ projects/index.php?$1 [L,NC]
```

The problem is that I always get a 404 error with the above.

How can I make this work properly?

**UPDATE**

This seems to have to do with how the server handles the redirects if a DNS record does not exist yet. In other words, since this is a development site, a domain has not been connected with the site. Once that has been set up, everything is working.

Comment: What if you add a trailing slash after `/~username/public_html` ? Also, you're forwarding `$1` to `projects/index.php` but you did not capture anything in your rule (`$1` is empty/null) but should be working even with that

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo. There is a trailing slash there. Yup, at the moment the $1 is empty. I'm going to add that after resolving the issue with the redirect. I corrected the typo.

Comment: Are you sure *mod_rewrite* and *htaccess* files are enabled ? Do you have other htaccess ?

Comment: Justin, I first thought that mod_rewrite wasn't working. I can create redirects with `RewriteRule ^work/?$ http://google.com [L]` which works. It's as if anything internally redirected is not working, only redirects to external sites.

Comment: That's a weird behaviour. I just tested it with your code and it works perfectly

Comment: What I suspected. This is happening on a Bluehost VPS server. Something must be misconfigured. Have to take it up with them.

Comment: Don't you have another `htaccess` in `/projects/` folder ? Or in another folder which could be in conflict

Comment: No other htaccess files are on the site, but I'll check again.

Comment: What's your Apache version ? For old versions, you need leading slash in your rule. You could try `RewriteRule ^/?work/?$ projects/index.php?$1 [L,NC]`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have to do with how the server handles the htaccess redirects if a DNS record does not exist yet for the site. In other words, since this is a development site, a domain has not been connected with the site and relative paths were used. Once that has been set up, everything is working.